# How to open the path I'm currently on my terminal on Files [Ubuntu]

Tags: linux, ubuntu, terminal

If I'm on a certain path on my terminal, let's say ~/Work/Project2, how can I open this folder directly from the terminal. I know I can use xdg-open ~/Work/Project2 however for bigger directories and for folder with spaces in the name and special characters it gets a bit slow. Is there any other command I can use or any way to shorten the current path?

I try to search on google for solutions and that's how I found the xdg-open [path] method however everything seems to be directed to opening files and not directories. I tried different commands like xdg-open cd or pwd and othes but they didn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the command `nautilus`. If you wanna open the current directory, you can easily run the command `nautilus ./`